# linux sort by multiple delimiters with numerical order

Tags: linux

I have data sorted by second column, but they were not what I expected.

```
0:1, 0:0,
0:2, 0:0,
1:1, 0:1,
1:2, 0:1,
0:11, 0:10,
0:12, 0:10, 
0:12, 0:11,
0:13, 0:11,
... (omit text) ...
1:192, 0:192,
2:192, 0:192,
0:3, 0:2,
0:4, 0:2,
... (omit text) ...
11:63, 9:63,
12:63, 9:63,
10:10, 9:7,
10:7, 9:7,
6:10, 9:7,
6:8, 9:7, 
...
```

Data were sorted by using `sort -t',' -k2,2 text.txt`. I wanted to sort them numerically by the second column, but `0:3, 0:2` followed `2:192, 0:192`. Moreover, first columns were not sorted in numerical order, because `10:7, 9:7,` followed `10:10, 9:7`.

I want to sort data numerically by the second column first and then the first column. In the second column, first number precedes second number, such as `2:192, 0:192` is followed by `11:63, 9:63`. So does the first column. What kind of commands I can use to get the results as shown below?

```
0:1, 0:0,
0:2, 0:0,
1:1, 0:1,
1:2, 0:1,
0:3, 0:2,
0:4, 0:2,
0:11, 0:10,
0:12, 0:10, 
0:12, 0:11,
0:13, 0:11,
... (omit text) ...
1:192, 0:192,
2:192, 0:192,
... (omit text) ...
6:8, 9:7,
6:10, 9:7, 
10:7, 9:7,
10:10, 9:7,
11:63, 9:63,
12:63, 9:63,
...
```

Comment: `0:3` is not a number. How can you sort numerically by it?

Comment: That's true. However, I want to manipulate them numerically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, convert the colons to commas to have one delimiter you can specify to sort.

```
tr : ,
```

Then, sort by four columns numerically (note the `n`'s)

```
sort -t, -k3,3n -k4,4n -k1,1n -k2,2n
```

Finally, convert the commas not followed by spaces back to colons:

```
sed 's/,\([^ ]\)/:\1/g'
```

Or, as a single pipeline:

```
tr : , < input \
| sort -t, -k3,3n -k4,4n -k1,1n -k2,2n \
| sed 's/,\([^ ]\)/:\1/g'
```